# WhenAnyValue: How to call an asynchronous function within select

Tags: reactive-programming, reactive, reactiveui

When setting up my observables in the constructor, how do I call an asynchronous function or a function that returns an IObservable during the transform/select function ?

I've tried various permutations within the select function, but they all result in compiler errors.

In the constructor:

```
this.WhenAnyValue(k => k.BaseProperty).Select(j => ObjectHelpers.GetAnotherValueThatReturnsObservable(j)).Select(m => m)
          .ToProperty(this, k=> k.PropertyToUpdate, out this.OaPHProperty, initialValue: false);
```

The other function

```
IObservable<bool> ObjectHelpers.GetAnotherValueThatReturnsObservable(j)
{
...this returns an IObservable that is used to update a property whenever BaseProperty changes. 
}
```

This is the error message
    The type arguments for method 'OAPHCreationHelperMixin.ToProperty(IObservable, TObj, Expression>, out ObservableAsPropertyHelper, TRet, bool, IScheduler)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

Answer (score 2):

The `SelectMany` method contains overloads for dealing with tasks and async methods. It has overloads which can handle cancellation. If you use this method instead of Select it will solve your issue.

Another alternative is to use `.Select(Observable.FromAsync(...method...).Switch()`. This approach will select a new observable. The switch will automatically dispose old values

Comment: @Ana  This works but can you help me understand why that's the case?